# Proving a sequent in natural deduction sequent style with elimination rules only

Tags: logic, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

Can we derive

$${p \hspace{0.1cm}  \& \hspace{0.1cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.01cm}  \rightarrow \hspace{0.01cm} \neg \thinspace q \hspace{0.2cm} \vdash \hspace{0.2cm}\bot}$$

using $\textit{only}$ elimination rules, structural rules and cut, in an intuitionistic natural deduction in sequent-style calculus (in which the rules are expressed with sequents but there are intro- and elim-rules that act only on consequents)?
The relevant elimination rules are:

$$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow A \rightarrow B \qquad \Delta \Rightarrow A}{\Gamma, \Delta \Rightarrow B}\hspace{0.1cm} \rightarrow Elim \hspace{0.1cm}$$ 
$$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow A \land B}{\Gamma \Rightarrow A}\hspace{0.1cm}  \& Elim_1 \hspace{0.1cm}$$ 
$$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow A \land B}{\Gamma \Rightarrow B}\hspace{0.1cm}  \& Elim_2 \hspace{0.1cm}$$ 
$$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow \bot}{\Gamma \Rightarrow A}\hspace{0.1cm}  \bot Elim \hspace{0.1cm}$$

This is claimed possible (but not proven) in

- Grigori Mints and Shane Steinert-Threlkeld [ADC method of proof search for
  intuitionistic propositional natural deduction](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/logcom/26/1/10.1093_logcom_ext032/2/ext032.pdf?Expires=1497620977&Signature=FyNnNdRZGPZPa9DwqZxPDxM25cFNJWtdqULMtVUsvT9btP1BJaUhuFdSWR2TbuUdCKVqx1xPU~Kh-MdG0IFP7nPHjyt~z8udwqewBnBENyjpXgMz1cNIaxiC5EHbXMww9i3JtWQyWSgcbBa3OnfjycGPQkoXPBhjclRhDcnqn4kT~0ft4RHRyiUxU~xQSHDWLKm5ixYStYjH1e6ivuLlKOk~wic5SpO0t4-4sBTbsWdebQxUvmItio0r5BWYLTUvsK2eon2rmX4lfDqbXOJly8qlNRPxNI4sUyg-YjGEG7qgX4V1GPSkjiO~~8X55c2CS7xq1xeeDdZCPaYXHwiWJQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q) (2016): page 396.

where a version of the natural deduction in sequent-style calculus is presented.

> Edit: I have managed to get to
>   $$\frac{\hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.01cm}  \rightarrow \hspace{0.01cm} (q \rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow (p \land q) \rightarrow \bot \qquad p \land q \hspace{0.3cm} \Rightarrow \hspace{0.3cm}  p \land q}{p \hspace{0.1cm}  \& \hspace{0.1cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.01cm}  \rightarrow \hspace{0.01cm} (q \rightarrow \bot) \hspace{0.2cm} \Rightarrow \hspace{0.2cm}\bot}_{\rightarrow \hspace{0.2cm} Elim}$$ 
>   But can't prove
>   $\hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.01cm}  \rightarrow \hspace{0.01cm} (q \rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow (p \land q) \rightarrow \bot$

Comment: Your $\to$Elim rule lacks a $\Delta$ somewhere in the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: Is $\neg A$ an abbreviation for $A\to \bot$ in your system? If so, I suggest you start by unfolding that in your goal. It should then be obvious that what you need to prove is a matter of two invocations of Modus Ponens.

Comment: Now the question has changed... :-) 1) assume $p \to \lnot q$; 2) assume $p \land q$; 3) derive $p$ from 2); 4) derive $q$ from 2); 5) derive $\lnot q$ from 1) and 3); 6) derive $\bot$ from 4) and 5) and now we need $\to$-intro to conclude with $\lnot (p \land q)$ from 2) and 6).

Comment: I have a follow-up here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325111/a-method-for-proving-sequents-in-natural-deduction-sequent-style-using-solely-el

Comment: As stated now, it is pretty trivially impossible.  None of your rules introduces a $\bot$ symbol or an unconstrained parameter.  When it comes to more general questions of "is X provable in natural deduction", you might want to look up normalization in natural deduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $p \land q \Rightarrow p \land q$ --- axiom

2) $p \land q \Rightarrow p $   - from 1) by $\land \text {Elim}_1$

3) $p \to \lnot q \Rightarrow p \to \lnot q$ --- axiom

4) $p \land q, p \to \lnot q \Rightarrow \lnot q$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\to \text {Elim}$

5) $p \land q, p \to \lnot q \Rightarrow q \to \bot$ --- from 4) rewriting $\lnot q$

6) $p \land q \Rightarrow q $ --- from 1) by $\land \text {Elim}_1$

> 7) $p \land q, p \to \lnot q \Rightarrow \bot$ --- from 5) and 6) by $\to \text {Elim}$.

---

Edit after OP's edit:

> 8) $p \to \lnot q \Rightarrow (p \land q) \to \bot$ --- from 7) by $\to \text {Intro}$.

---

---

*Comment*

In conclusion, we have proved the well-known:

> $p \to \lnot q \vdash \lnot (p \land q)$

in a [normal form](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H9): first applying only elimination rules and then the introduction rules.