# A method for proving sequents in natural deduction sequent style using solely elimination rules and structural rules

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, intuitionistic-logic, sequent-calculus

In a previous question, [Proving a sequent in natural deduction sequent style with elimination rules only](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325050/proving-a-sequent-in-natural-deduction-sequent-style-with-elimination-rules-only), $${p \hspace{0.1cm}  \& \hspace{0.1cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.01cm}  \rightarrow \hspace{0.01cm} \neg \thinspace q \hspace{0.2cm} \vdash \hspace{0.2cm}\bot}$$

was shown using only elimination rules of a natural deduction sequent style calculus (the relevant elimination rules being in [Proving a sequent in natural deduction sequent style with elimination rules only](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325050/proving-a-sequent-in-natural-deduction-sequent-style-with-elimination-rules-only)).

In

- Grigori Mints and Shane Steinert-Threlkeld [ADC method of proof search for
  intuitionistic propositional natural deduction](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/logcom/26/1/10.1093_logcom_ext032/2/ext032.pdf?Expires=1497620977&Signature=FyNnNdRZGPZPa9DwqZxPDxM25cFNJWtdqULMtVUsvT9btP1BJaUhuFdSWR2TbuUdCKVqx1xPU~Kh-MdG0IFP7nPHjyt~z8udwqewBnBENyjpXgMz1cNIaxiC5EHbXMww9i3JtWQyWSgcbBa3OnfjycGPQkoXPBhjclRhDcnqn4kT~0ft4RHRyiUxU~xQSHDWLKm5ixYStYjH1e6ivuLlKOk~wic5SpO0t4-4sBTbsWdebQxUvmItio0r5BWYLTUvsK2eon2rmX4lfDqbXOJly8qlNRPxNI4sUyg-YjGEG7qgX4V1GPSkjiO~~8X55c2CS7xq1xeeDdZCPaYXHwiWJQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q) (2016): page 396.

using $${p \hspace{0.1cm}  \& \hspace{0.1cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.01cm}  \rightarrow \hspace{0.01cm} \neg \thinspace q \hspace{0.2cm} \vdash \hspace{0.2cm}\bot}$$ as an example (and defining $\neg p$ as $p \rightarrow \bot$), they propose a method for obtaining sequents derivable by direct chaining (that is derivable by elimination rules, cut and structural rules only):

> "To see whether this sequent is derivable by direct chaining, we $\textit{saturate}$ $\Gamma=\{\hspace{0.09cm} p \hspace{0.2cm} \& \hspace{0.2cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \rightarrow \neg q \hspace{0.09cm} \}$ with the
>   conclusions of all applicable elimination rules (i.e. elimination rules where the consequents of the
>   premises are in $\Gamma$ ). This saturation procedure generates, in order, the following sets:
>
> $\Gamma_1 =\{\hspace{0.09cm} p \hspace{0.2cm} \& \hspace{0.2cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \rightarrow \neg q,\hspace{0.2cm} p,\hspace{0.2cm} q \hspace{0.09cm} \}$
>
> $\Gamma_2=\{\hspace{0.09cm} p \hspace{0.2cm} \& \hspace{0.2cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \rightarrow \neg q, \hspace{0.2cm} p, \hspace{0.2cm}q, \hspace{0.2cm} q \rightarrow \bot \hspace{0.09cm} \}$
>
> $\Gamma_3=\{\hspace{0.09cm} p \hspace{0.2cm} \& \hspace{0.2cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \rightarrow \neg q ,\hspace{0.2cm}p, \hspace{0.2cm}q,\hspace{0.2cm} q \rightarrow \bot, \hspace{0.2cm} \bot \hspace{0.09cm} \}$

They claim that, because $\bot∈\Gamma_3$, we can derive $${p \hspace{0.1cm}  \& \hspace{0.1cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.01cm}  \rightarrow \hspace{0.01cm} \neg \thinspace q \hspace{0.2cm} \vdash \hspace{0.2cm}\bot}$$

by elimination rules only.

- Why does it follow from the fact that because $\bot∈\Gamma_3$ that we can derive the sequent by elimination rules only? Could you give another example of this method of proving sequents via elimination rules only?
- They speak of 'the conclusions of all applicable elimination rules (i.e. elimination rules where the consequents of the
  premises are in $\Gamma$)'. But what is the reason for excluding repetitions in this method, and thereby generating?

> $\Gamma_{1A}=\{\hspace{0.09cm} p \hspace{0.2cm} \& \hspace{0.2cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \rightarrow \neg q ,\hspace{0.2cm} p, \hspace{0.2cm}q \hspace{0.2cm},\hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{p} \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{&} \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{q},\hspace{0.2cm}\textbf{p} \rightarrow \textbf{$\neg$ q} \}$
>
> $\Gamma_{2A}=\{\hspace{0.09cm} p \hspace{0.2cm} \& \hspace{0.2cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \rightarrow \neg q ,\hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.2cm},q \hspace{0.2cm}, q \rightarrow \bot, \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{p} \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{&} \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{q},\hspace{0.2cm}\textbf{p} \rightarrow \textbf{$\neg$ q} \}$
>
> $\Gamma_{3A}=\{\hspace{0.09cm} p \hspace{0.2cm} \& \hspace{0.2cm} q, \hspace{0.2cm} p \rightarrow \neg q ,\hspace{0.2cm} p \hspace{0.2cm},q \hspace{0.2cm}, q \rightarrow \bot, \hspace{0.2cm} \bot, \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{p} \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{&} \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{q},\hspace{0.2cm}\textbf{p} \rightarrow \textbf{$\neg$ q} \}$

Is it just the fact that we are using sets $\Gamma_1,...$? But then why not use multisets, in which case repetition would be important? What forces the appeal to sets in the procedure?

Comment: If you read the answer to your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325050/proving-a-sequent-in-natural-deduction-sequent-style-with-elimination-rules-only/2325068#2325068) you can easily check that the six formulas in $\Gamma_3$ are exactly the conclusion of the seven step in my proof ("modulo" the rewriting of $\lnot q$ as $q \to \bot$).